# Install 18.04 server without network connection

Tags: networking, server, system-installation

The latest version of Ubuntu server (18.04) seems to demand network configuration and refuse to boot without it. I have no desire to connect the server in question to the internet for anything, and have installed previous versions of Ubuntu server without network no questions asked.

Is a network connection an absolute requirement for the latest version of Ubuntu server? Or is there something I'm missing?

The installation cannot proceed past the network configuration page unless an ethernet connection is active, by my current estimates. I have no ethernet network within range of the machine so can't test it on an internet-less network. I only have WiFi within immediate range (which does have internet access) but it won't recognise the device and it *should* be simpler to get the installation to happen without any updates than to go to the effort of finding the drivers to support the WiFi adapter.

Note that this is NOT a duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu Server without network connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421512/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-without-network-connection) since the new installer seems to be the real problem here.

Comment: Can you update your question with details of where you get stuck , what you have tried to fix the problem, and why the second answer in the link you gave or the mini .iso does not solve your problem ? Otherwise your question is unclear at best and seems to me to be a duplicate. If you feel the installer has a bug, file a bug report.

Comment: The installation falls over at network configuration which there seems to be no way to bypass. The first answer details skipping the network configuration by pressing Esc, which simply goes to the previous installation page in the latest version. The second answer seems to be addressing the installation of packages (which is presumably not the reason that I can't bypass network configuration).

Comment: And the mini iso ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD . You will almost certainly need to file a bug report against the server installer

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that an ISO which actually installs packages from the internet at install time would help me to install without an internet connection? Am I really confused or have I mislead you by linking the other question?

Comment: Yes the installer  seems to require a network connection. The mini.iso require internet... A fast workaround will be to plug some cable and switch/hub to pass the network step of install process

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu 18.04 without an internet connection when using the "standard" ISO. (not the live server)

You can download the standard one here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/

Comment: Might be worth updating this answer to note that eventually this will probably change, assuming the new installer receives adequate maintenance. Thanks regardless, hopefully this will help save a few other headaches in the interim.

Comment: I just reverted back to 16.04 thinking i could get a wifi only working, no network tools installed with it.. /etc/network/interfaces was a pain so this is my preferred method. + 1

Comment: You saved an hour of my time clicking around...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 installer requires at least one ethernet interface having link up status. Connecting the server to powered up switch without any other devices will make the installer happy but you cannot use the "new" installer without a network.

Comment: It looks like for 22.04, Ubuntu have removed the standard installer image - Atleast, I can't seem to find it. Here's where I'm looking: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/22.04/release/

Answer (score 2):

Originally downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Live ISO.  The installer recognized my wifi network card but could not sign in to the WIFI network and therefore the installation would not let me continue.  Following a suggestion in this thread downloaded the ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso and installed it on a USB drive.  The installer on this ISO recognized my WiFi card and allowed me to login to the WiFi network.  The ISO is located in Ubuntu.com -> Download -> Ubuntu Server -> Use the Traditional installer -> Download the Alternate Installer -> 64-bit PC (AMD64) server install image.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1750819) in the new installer. Until it is fixed, you can use the traditional installer as dhelios points out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently.

I solved it by manually configuring a bogus IPv4 address.
Even without Internet access, the installer was able to proceed with the installation.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you correctly configure nameservers, gateway and netmask? Even though it was a bogus IP address, I used the correct info for the network. I'm just wondering if it may have an effect.

Comment: I think I did that, but may be it required a network link also (I hadn't a cable to connect it to anything).

Comment: It works if I manually configure an IP address and connect it to any network, but it needs a network connection all the same.

Comment: This worked for me without any issues. Not sure why it didn't work for others.