# installing ubuntu 18.04 Lts server with "old" iso without internet

Tags: networking, server

I know there is a simular question but it is marked as solved, which doesn't seem true anymore. I followed the advice to use the alternative installation.  But I cann't go on in the installation process without specifing an accessable mirror.  I do have actually internet accass from the machine in question but by a wifi adapter tp-link TL-WN725N which is not offered to configure during the installation process.

The question is, can I setup ubuntu 18.04 LTS on this machine in any way?

E.g. is there an "open shell" command on the setup menu which maybe allows me to configure the tp-link?

Or installing any other version of Ubuntu which is known to function with this hardware configuration and the downgrading(18.04 Desktop) or upgrading e.g. from 16.04 to 18.04 server?

Thank you for your time, Stephan

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do the installation:

1. Disable the `Download updates while installing ubuntu`
   [image]
2. provide driver and firmware of your wifi adapter during the installation process

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I don't have this screen but a terminal installation (my iso: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042364/install-18-04-server-without-network-connection/1071034#1071034 – but it doesn't work for me).  Which iso of Ubuntu are you referring to?