# No network connection during Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, ethernet

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an old HP DL360-G5 server. The server is equipped with two Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5708 ethernet controllers. I have one of the ethernet ports on my machine connected to my switch and the lights on the port show connection and activity.

When I make it to the step 4 of the Ubuntu install process (via USB drive) I am asked to configure the network interfaces. Two interfaces are shown ("enp0s3" & "enp0s5"). Both interfaces fail to obtain an IP address using DHCP and also fail when an IP address is provided manually.

From the installation page there is an option to create a "bond", I am not sure if this is necessary to simple get a connection to the internet through either one of my network interfaces. Finally after some research online I see that there might be the requirement of installing the BNX2 driver.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there something obvious that I am missing here, perhaps I need to
   create a bond in order to obtain an IP address?
2. Does the fact that the two network interfaces show up in the Ubuntu install mean that they are configured correctly and should work if provided the correct configuration?
3. Do I need to install the BNX2 driver, and if so how do I do this prior to arriving at the network interface part of the Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Why don't you skip the network part and troubleshoot it in the installed system, if still needed?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't have any option to skip this step, it won't let me continue until I've configured a network interface. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042364/install-18-04-server-without-network-connection?rq=1

Comment: So I probably could (by using a different ISO) install without a network connection. I'm wondering if I can avoid that and get it working during install...

Comment: Hey are you installing the server version? Please do read the answers in the link.

Comment: I have tried that. I now seem to be getting a GRUB error that is related to the installer not being able to download the correct packages from the internet.

Comment: Alternatively you can install the desktop version. If you need server specific services later those can be installed in the desktop version. The main difference is the server being headless, no desktop environment. It's only useful for pure server roles.