# Why doesn't Ubuntu Server come with wireless-tools package installed?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I am having to haul my giant case downstairs to the living room router when dad's at work not to bother him and lug through my cables bin to find an ethernet cable to temporarily use a wired ethernet connection just to install the package in order to get WiFi working.

Is it typical practice to run a server on a wired connection? Because I don't intend on doing that.

I can provide my Ubuntu and kernel versions if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Your version number of Ubuntu Server and the make and model of the wifi adapter would be helpful to know. If you don't know the latter, please open a terminal and run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` to find the WiFi adapter make and model. Then, please click [edit] and add that very important information to your question (not as a Comment, please). Also, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042364/install-18-04-server-without-network-connection

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is typical practice to run a server on a wired connection, for wired Ethernet provides connectivity orders of magnitude faster than WiFi does.  Therefore, wireless-tools is not one of the standard packages of a server install.