# Install Ubuntu server 22.04 without internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, 22.04

From [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042364/install-18-04-server-without-network-connection), I've seen that there are two versions of installers for Ubuntu Server 18.04, which one uses the internet, but the other doesn't.
On installing Ubuntu Server 22.04 I get error on the following log:

```
configuring apt
  curtin command in-target
```

Why there's no standard installer for the 22.04 version on [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/22.04/release/)?
How should one now install Ubuntu Server 22.04 while not having connection to the internet?

[Here's the installer log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXKjC.png)

Comment: If you have problems with the installer, you can extract a compressed image file and get an installed system directly from [**this link**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/). You find more details at [**this link**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) how to use it. In Ubuntu there are many tools that can extract and clone it to the target drive, for example [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). In Windows you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie).

Comment: @user535733 I see. The iso files worked fine on disabling the NICs.

Comment: @sudoodus Isn't there nicer documentations on this? A forum doesn't seem to be good way for organizing knowledge.

Comment: The official way to get Ubuntu Server is provided by Canonical, and for amd64 architecture (PC computers), there are only iso files with installers. For other architectures, e.g. RPi, there are official compressed image files. Now Canonical is publishing compressed image files also for amd64 architecture, but silently 'as a service to the developers'. Take it or leave it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to disable the network adapters for the installer to stop running `sudo apt update`.
It seems like the installer can get better at asking the user whether or not the given links have got an internet connection or not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Download from this [link](https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso). Burn to usb. Install.

Comment: this link is purely a download, where is it coming from? Is it from an official Ubuntu site? If so, can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421430/edit) your answer to include the link to the page itself, so users can verify the source of the download?

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: This is what I did, too. However an installation w/o internet connection is not possible using this image. It will try to connect to the internet. Possibly forever.

Comment: As a workaround, I will use now the Desktop installer. I know that this one will work.