# install 22.04.3 server offline - no network access

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization, offline

Ubuntu 20.04 host running multiple ubuntu guest servers

I'm trying to install a new 22.04.3 server, but the install insists on a network connection. Because I have non-standard MTU settings, I need to complete the install without a network, after which I can fix the MTU problem manually.

There doesn't seem to be an option to install without network.

I need to either set MTU in virt-install, or complete the install without any network. Can anyone suggest a way of doing either?

Comment: I have not tried a server install... but using the desktop install ISO you can click "Try Ubuntu" and then set up network communications (the very same way that you would in any installed / active Ubuntu) before doing the actual install.

Comment: @DanielT The question author's self-answer looked OK to me, so I voted to leave this question open.

Comment: I retracted my flag. The link to https://askubuntu.com/q/1421429 was the simpler solution, but I see the self-answer contains new information about the shell option that would help additional people

Comment: I didn't make it clear that I'm installing a new GUEST. I think it's a rare case where anyone would want to do this without a network, but this is a problem with the MTU. I haven't tried not having a network when installing the guest and not sure if I can add it into the xml file later. I'm not expert on KVM etc.

Answer (score 1):

partially answering my own question...

during the network connections dialogue (VNC) if you click the HELP button top right, it gives an option to enter a shell. From there I added an <mtu: 1492> clause to the netplan yaml, then did netplan apply, and everything worked.

This is a temporary fix but allows the install to complete, after which I can edit netplan permanently via VNC.

It would still be nice to install completely without a network - not sure why you can't.